# Form Text Input with an image as submit button (input type="image"), and the button is misaligned

Tags: html, forms

HTML:

```
<form action="search.php" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="q" value="Search for an item..." width="150" style="border: solid 1px black; padding: 3px;" />
    <input type="image" src="images/search_icon.png" style="width: 24px; height="30px;" /> 
</form>
```

What I get:

[image]

by the way, if I try use padding on just the button, it moves the whole form down.

Comment: You have an extra `"` in the middle of your `style` attribute.

Comment: oh yeah, changed it but the buttons still in the same place.

Comment: set a `height` attribute inside the styling of your `input` box.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the vertical-align property on the input to middle.

```
input {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/wMYX4/1/)**.

Comment: What's the link to your image?

Comment: Since your magnifying glass image has some extra white space on it, you'll need to position it and then adjust. See http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/wMYX4/2/

Comment: This worked. Make sure that the elements' positions are relative